# Fail to run SUMO Tutorials/TraCI4Traffic Lights

Tags: python, sumo

I tried to run tutorials of SUMO.

Here is the website:

> http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Tutorials/TraCI4Traffic_Lights

I typed this command:

```
sumo-gut data/cross.sumocfg
```

Then I ran:

```
python3 runner.py
```

And Here comes the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runner.py", line 122, in <module>
    traci.start([sumoBinary, "-c", "data/cross.sumocfg","--tripinfo-output", "tripinfo.xml"])
  File "/Users/xieweian/sumo/tools/traci/__init__.py", line 96, in start
    sumoProcess = subprocess.Popen(cmd + ["--remote-port", str(port)])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sumo-guiD': 'sumo-guiD'
```

What should I do to run this demo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to start sumo-gui manually, the runner.py should do that for you and it does not seem to find your sumo-guiD. But apparently you already modified the script or use some modified version because in the most recent version the scripts looks for sumo-gui not for sumo-guiD. Please also check whether your SUMO_HOME environment variable is set and points to the correct directory. Which version of sumo are you running?

Answer (score 0):

```
export SUMO_HOME=/usr/share/sumo
```

It works temporarily for me in Ubuntu. Each time I run .py python, I have to add this command above

Comment: If you need a path to be always added, you can set the path in your `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` file